# DocuSign: Envelope related mails received even after disabling in email preferences

Tags: docusignapi

We're using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.13.0) We are developing an integration with DocuSign.

In *Email Preferences* settings of the account, I have disabled all the options under *User* and *API User* to stop receiving any envelope related mail from DocuSign.

Yet, the account holder receives mail when an envelope is completed, declined or voided.

Is there any option to stop receiving envelope related mails from DocuSign completely?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the options you set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are user level and account-level settings for email. Make sure all of them are unchecked in both places.

**This is under "My Preferences" for user level:**
[image]

**This is under "Settings" for account level:**

[image]

Comment: I missed the User level settings. Thank You.