# DocuSign: Even after disabling envelope related mails, envelope history reports "<sender_name>received a printable copy of the envelope"

Tags: docusignapi

We're using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.13.0) for integration.

I have disabled all the emails sent via DocuSign.

When an envelope is sent and completed via SDK, in the envelope history there is a activity entry that says "<sender_name> received a printable copy of the envelope". But, the sender did not receive any mail from DocuSign.

Is this an known issue ?

Comment: How did you disable the emails?

Comment: Disabled Emails as mentioned below: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736657/docusign-envelope-related-mails-received-even-after-disabling-in-email-preferen ,                                                               Suppressed emails via SDK, by setting "suppress_emails" to True for every recipient,            Also In Email Preferences settings of the account, I have disabled all the options under User and API User to stop receiving any envelope related mail from DocuSign.

Answer (score 1):

If the Sender's user was created before the Account notification defaults were updated then you will need to login as the sender to disable all notifications at the user level.

Comment: I have observed that the history "<sender_name> received a printable copy of the envelope" is added, only after the envelope is placed on the purging queue using the SDK method. Also, no mail is sent to the sender or receiver. I also have disabled every mail in my_preferences -> notifications.                                                                                                           Other than updating the purgeState using envelope update in SDK, am I missing any other parameters to suppress the entry in history?